# Are there any arbitrary restrictions on maximum image pixel size in IE and Webkit mobile?

Tags: html, browser, graphics, cross-browser

A recent project made use of very pixel-large (~5e3px2) but still byte-small (~100kb — GIF) images, which both IE8 and iOS Safari refused to render. Both seem aware of the image size, but simply do not render them. A practical solution is to slice the image, but are there any documented arbitrary restrictions on maximum image pixel size for these browsers?

Comment: I once had a 40,000x20,000 PNG image (at 1bpp - black/white) and it rendered just fine in all browsers I cared to test it in. Of course, I then sliced it up Google Maps-style to only show the part of the image that was in the scroll view.

Comment: Possibly a case of bad encoding then… Will produce test cases later…

Comment: Image rendered alone (http://domain.com/big.gif), HTML img or CSS background image? Does it render when saved as PNG-8, PNG-24 or JPG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari has a 3-megabit buffer for non JPG images. Anything larger than that will not display. Calculate size = w * h * 8 for GIFs.

Any element using CSS "Filters" on IE8 will fail to display on anything with a dimension bigger than 4096 pixels.