# Large image and javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using pannellum (http://www.mpetroff.net/archives/2012/08/28/pannellum-1-2/) which uses Three.js and I am using it to work with local files. It works fine for small files, but the image that I have is 5000 * 10000, and it doesn't load them. What is the limitation and how can I use it with large images. Can I load the image using an img tag and inject that image into the application? In the code I found that I have:

```
var panoimage = new Image();
```

Can I replace it with something such as his?

```
 var panoimage = document.getElementById('PanImage');
```

Where is the source code for Image()? Is it part of JS? I could not find any information on this class.

### EDIT 1

I made the following changes to pannellum so it loads image from an image on html instead of loaading it dynamically.

In pannellum.htm I added the following html:

```
 <img id='panimage' src="000063.jpg" style="visibility: collapse;"/>
```

in pannellum.js, I change line 104 to :

```
var panoimage = document.getElementById('panimage');
```

I also commented out the

```
panoimage.onerror = function() {
```

and so the code which should be called after image was downloaded called straight away ( since by the time that we reach to his point image already downloaded)

Also I commented out the line that set the source of image.

It doesn't download image. it only show a black screen.

Comment: Can you give us the image and I'll just try to render the thing. We need more code. Are you not using `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('imgpath', NULL, function () { // callback here })`? Try loading it up as a texture using that function and then apply it to a plane.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that various browsers will take it upon themselves not to render images they deem to be too large (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317112/are-there-any-arbitrary-restrictions-on-maximum-image-pixel-size-in-ie-and-webki) I asked a while back). Sadly, this depends on the user agent. Canvas has abstractions for dealing with this sometimes but last time I was dealing with very large images in DHTML, I had to give up (even slicing them up into tiny bite-sized pieces just ended up with them not rendering after a while).

`new Image()` is an old DOM method to produce an image element from scratch outside of the document – [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images). That first line of yours is the equivalent of:

```
var panoimage = document.createElement('img');
```

The line you've replaced it with effectively takes an image that's already somewhere in the document rather than creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: I made some test and I can download image by placing a <img> tag on html. Now I am trying to see how I can cange code to use the image that already downloaded by img tag. I think the reason that I am not able to work with my images are that three.js crashes when it tries to render paart of that image into screen.

Comment: Could be any number of things. Can you show us your code (for example by saving a demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net)? Without seeing it, it's impossible to guess what mistakes might be happening.

Comment: I amnot familar with jsfiddle so I need to go and learn it, but for now, I add some code to question that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Pannellum source code, it seems to use the WebGL renderer of Three.js. WebGL has a limit on texture size (and thus in the image size it can render) imposed by your GPU. You can check yours ("Max texture size") here: http://jsfiddle.net/DA7wr/

Another thing that came into mind was using non-power-of-two image size with [wrong kind of texture parameters](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support), but as the Pannellum demo also has NPOT image, I guess this is not the issue.